# How to get the key/value from python dict into requests for get method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, request

I'm trying to get the specific values from dict and use in the requests module to make the get requests.

```
clusters = {
    'cluster_1':'https://cluster_1.something.com/api',
    'cluster_2':'https://cluster_2.something.com/api'
}
```

Code:

```
def getCsv():
    for i in clusters:
        r = requests.get(i.values(), headers=headers, params=params)
        with open("input.csv", "w") as f:
            f.writelines(r.text.splitlines(True))
        df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
        return df

getCsv()
```

Am I doing it right?

Also final step is to print the clusters key into output csv using below code.

```
with open(rb'output.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
        timestamp = datetime.now()        
        df = getCsv()
        if 'Name' in df.columns:
            df.rename(columns = {"Name": "team", "Total": "cost"}, inplace = True)
        df.insert(0, 'date',timestamp)
        df.insert(1, 'resource_type', "pod")
        df.insert(2, 'resource_name', "kubernetes")
        df.insert(3, 'cluster_name', i.keys)
        df.drop(["CPU", "GPU", "RAM", "PV", "Network", "LoadBalancer", "External", "Shared", "Efficiency"], axis=1, inplace=True)
        df['team'] = df['team'].map(squads).fillna(df['team'])
        df.groupby(["date","resource_type","resource_name","cluster_name","team"]).agg({"cost": sum}).reset_index().to_csv(out_file, index=False)
```

But seems not working, any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getCsv` is screwed up. You're passing multiple urls to `requests.get` by passing `i.values()` and you're returning in the first iteration of the for loop.

Try extracting the loop from the function and reformulating the function like this:

```py
def get_cluster_df(url, **kwargs):
    r = requests.get(url, **kwargs)
    with open("input.csv", "w") as f:
        f.writelines(r.text.splitlines(True))
    return pd.read_csv("input.csv")

headers = ...
params = ...

dfs = {}
for name, url in clusters.items():
    dfs[name] = get_cluster_df(url, headers=headers, params=params)
```

You will end up with a dictionary `dfs` which will look like:

```py
{
    'cluster_1': pd.DataFrame(),
    'cluster_2': pd.DataFrame()
}
```